# SparkSQL with HIVE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to user HIVEContext with SparkSQL, and when I create

```
val hContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

I get that hive is not a member in spark.sql, when I looked into the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) it says that I should use `sbt/sbt -Phive assembly/assembly`
But how can I run that? I don't understand what should I replace assembly with?

Comment: did you download spark assembly or you compiled it from source??

Answer (score 2):

To get hive support, you have to download the source and then build it using `sbt` or `maven`. Here is a list of steps to do so:

1. Download the Spark source from: [Spark Downloads](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), make sure you select 'package type' as 'source code'. For convience here is the direct link to download [Spark 1.3 source](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).
2. Once downloaded extract and compile using `maven`, as maven is the recommended way to build moving forward:

   ```
   tar xzf spark-[version].tgz
   cd spark-[version]
   ./make-distribution.sh --skip-java-test --tgz -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Pyarn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver
   ```
3. This will create a tar ball in the project root directory as `spark-[version]-bin-2.4.0.tgz`, which could be conveniently shipped to the cluster or extracted out on a single machine.

Comment: How can I compile with maven?

Comment: I'm a newbie can you please explain to me where can I set my code in this new project?

Comment: Actually, `mvn` is already part of the source download (located in `build/mvn`). Just use the `make_distribution.sh` which will take care of using the inbuilt mvn binary. What do you mean by "set my code in this new project?"